# Name of each item when comparing two things

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, programming

I am thinking specifically of comparing two files using `diff` in linux or git (for those of you familiar with it), but this relates, I think, to any comparison.

I have two files.  `File 1` and `File 2`.  `File 1` is the older, original file - the one that is the base of comparison.  `File 2` is the 'draft' file - the one that will be compared against `File 1` to assert differences, in this case additions or reductions in lines of text.

I want to compare them - how can I refer to each file?

My ideas:

**File 1**: comparer, original, base, original, current, active
**File 2**: comparee, draft, new

Is there an agreed upon naming convention for this scenario?

Comment: `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: i want something desciptive about the role that these files are playing.  `foo` and `bar` are good placeholders when the role is undefined or unimportant, but that's not the case here

Comment: *removes tongue from cheek*

Comment: *hangs head* i see.

Comment: I knew someone else than me was also trying to figure this out. xD Gotta love the StackExchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just about every diff (comparison) system I've used has labelled these ***source*** and ***target*** respectively.

Note that this convention does privilege the file named first -- the ***source*** -- as the canonical, "normative", reference. For example, if file1 has a line file2 lacks, then tools following this convention will say the line has been *deleted*  (*to produce the target*) rather than *added* (because a *source* isn't *produced*).

For the sake of having a reference, the [Wikipedia article on data differencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_differencing) uses the terms this way, which means they will probably be clear enough to your audience without a lot of introduction.

---

By the way, for a little bit of fun, the two files, collectively, can be called the "*comparands*" (viz "*operands*", "*summands*", etc).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be one of these circumstances where you have answered your own question.

> I have two files.  File 1 and File 2.  File 1 is the older, **original** file - the one that is the base of comparison.  File 2 is the '**draft**' file - the one that will be compared against File 1 to assert differences, in this case additions or reductions in lines of text.

[Original](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/original)

> a primary form or type from which varieties are derived.

[Draft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/draft?s=t)

> a preliminary form of any writing, subject to revision, copying, etc.

The words you have suggested are already clear enough not to cause confusion.

Comment: yeah, `base` came to me when i was writing it, and that seemed like the best until Dan's answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the majority of definitions of the `diff` command, the technical terms for the two files are the `from_file` and the `to_file`.

The important thing to note here is that the command makes no underlying assumption of relationship between the two files- so `original` and `draft` or `old` and `new` arent correct in the context of the command, but may be correct in the context of your application of it.

> In the simplest case, diff compares the contents of the two files
>   *from-file* and *to-file*.

<sup>source:[about.com](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm), [unixhelp.ed.ac.uk](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff)</sup>

Indeed, simply using `FileA` and `FileB`, or `File1` and `File2` (etc) could suffice, unless you wish to imply an implicit relationship.